# DIV float:left with another div with display: inline-block wraps

Tags: html, css

I have the following code;

```
<div id="first" style="float: left">
</div>
<div id="second">
    <div id="1" style="display: inline-block;">
    </div>

    <div id="2" style="display: inline-block;">
    </div>
    ......
    <div  id= "n" style="display: inline-block;">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the content in `#second` is taller than the content in `#first`,
then the child `div`'s in `#second` start a new line below `#first`.

I want them to come below the second div only.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle example.

Comment: use `display: inline-block` to the first div instead of using `float` css property.

Comment: jsfiddle example is http://jsfiddle.net/pWjAL/ I want all the div(s) in "second" to act like table cells one below the other.

Comment: Mr_Green, tried display: inline-block it displays weird result, the content in div first moves to the right in firefox

Answer (score 5):

One simple way of doing this without having to set any widths or margins is to trigger a block formatting context for `#second`.

Apply the following CSS:

```
#second {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

See the demo at **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/jhtSp/)**

For more information about **block formatting contexts**, see:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Comment: coool.. :) I was not aware of this.

Comment: @Mr_Green Very useful feature especially when dealing with floats.

Answer (score 1):

if you are aware of the maximum width/width of the first div then just apply that width value as `margin-left` to the second div.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pWjAL/1/)**

**Updated**: (*if you are not aware of the width*)

```
#second{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pWjAL/6/)

Comment: This solves the problem, but in reality the first div's width might vary.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block instead of float.

try:

```
#first, #second{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

That will make sure the two are separate as long as they are next to each other, so have to have a width.

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/CVDXS/)

**EDIT**

or yes, if you don't know width

```
#first, #second{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/CVDXS/1/)

Comment: If you try this, you will see that the `#second` starts below `#first`.  In this case, `#second` expands to fill the width of the page which forces the line to wrap.

Comment: Yes, sorry - for that to work you need to know width. table-cell is what you'd need for unknown width